# Why does Visualforce ignore setting apex:selectList and apex:inputCheckbox values if manipulated (disabled) by jQuery?

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I have a VF Page where I wanted to alter an `<apex:selectList value="{!dependentSelection}">`'s `options` dynamically like a dependent picklist with another `apex:selectList`.  I felt using `apex:actionSupport` took too long to update, so I manipulated the dependent `apex:selectList`'s `option`s  with jQuery, but in doing so,  Visualforce would no longer set `dependentSelection` in the controller.

I found a question, [Apex:selectList value not getting set in controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11965/apexselectlist-value-not-getting-set-in-controller), and the solution is to use an HTML  and then set it's value to an `<apex:hiddenInput value="{!dependentSelection}"/>`.

---

Also in this VF Page, I denoted many selections with an `<apex:inputCheckbox>` and altered their `checked` and `disabled` properties so that only one selection per section could be chosen and that one selection is always selected:

### Example:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!section.itemList}" var="item">
    <tr>
        <td><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!item.isSelected}" styleClass="selection" onclick="validateSelection(this);"/></td>
        <td><apex:outputField value="{!item.record.Label__c}"/></td>
    </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

With JavaScript

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict;

// on load
j$('.selection:checked').prop('disabled', true);

function validateSelection(thar){
    j$('.selection').each(function(){
        if(this == thar)
            j$(this).prop('checked', true).prop('disabled', true);
        else
            j$(this).prop('checked', false).prop('disabled', false);
}
```

Using this technique worked fine for me in my sandbox, and when I tested this in production with my browser it also worked.

### Weird Part # 1

I tried this same technique in a new VF Page (using the same API Version 31) but it did **not** work.  The variables were mysteriously not getting set in the controller (all the `inputCheckbox` variables came back as `false` in the controller).  The culprit turned out to be using the `validateSelection` jQuery function and the problem was the same as [Apex:selectList value not getting set in controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11965/apexselectlist-value-not-getting-set-in-controller) so the solution was again using a `hiddenInput`.

The weird part was the old VF Page's `validateSelection` would still work fine without hidden inputs, but the new VF Page's `validateSelection` would **not** work without hidden inputs.

### Weird Part #2

In testing, everything would work fine on the old VF Page for my boss using Chrome version 34, but it did **not** work for our Client using Chrome version 37.   There is word that updating to Chrome (beta) version 38 does work for this technique on `inputCheckboxes`.  Could this be a browser compatability issue?  Testing on IE 11 works for my boss, but I still have run my own tests.

---

Now how can it work for me on one Page but not another??  I'm curious to what the reason is behind this (like what's going on behind the scenes with Visualforce) and if there is any hope that this technique may be supported in the future.

Currently, I believe it is necessary use the `hiddenInput` technique now and in the future, but please confirm this is necessary.

Also, I believe the `hiddenInput` technique is necessary only if JavaScript is altering an `input`'s properties or child `options`.  (Using `j$(this).addClass('highlight');` causes no issues.)

Comment: Disabled elements are not posted with the form data. If you remove the `.prop('disabled', true)` and test it, does it behave the way that you expect?

Comment: Yes, that solves my issue.

Comment: Any idea why the Old Page still works even though I leave the checked checkboxes disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabled form elements are not "[successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls)" and the browser is not required to submit those with the form data. I'm not sure why your old page works, I suspect it's not doing exactly what you think it's doing but that's really beside the point.

Proper form state is key, if the data is to be submitted by the browser to the server it must be in a successful control. Controls which are disabled cannot be successful and therefore aren't posted.

[W3.org 17.13 Form Submission](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13)

As an alternate solution, I would suggest that your script sets the `readonly` attribute instead of the `disabled` attribute.

[W3.org 17.12.2 Read-only controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.2)

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict;

// on load
j$('.selection:checked').prop('readonly', true);

function validateSelection(thar){
    j$('.selection').each(function(){
        if(this == thar)
            j$(this).prop('checked', true).prop('readonly', true);
        else
            j$(this).prop('checked', false).prop('readonly', false);
}
```

Comment: the readonly is optimal

Comment: Setting checkboxes to "readonly" isn't working as well as I thought it would.  Checked & readonly checkboxes won't uncheck, but I can check unchecked & readonly checkboxes (say that 5 times fast)

Comment: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_DISABLED.html -- I think the best way through is to use disabled but set disabled = false onsubmit

Comment: Per the spec, `readonly` isn't a [permitted attribute of the checkbox element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html) - this is probably the reason you're seeing that odd behavior. The script to re-enable the elements on submit is a solid solution and will do the job just fine.